Fine-tune llama 3.1 with domain specific terms
New to working with LLMs and I'd like to fine-tune Llama3.1 Instruct on domain specific terms. The terms are about 10K medical terms, which are groups of words ranging from one to thirteen words. Which libraries can I use to fine-tune Llama3.1 for this task? Also, how do I handle the multiple word terms? Do I break them up into single words?

I was able to check for unknown tokens with huggingface AutoTokenizer. Good news, there was none.
My problem is that the tokenizer is breaking up the terms into single characters, which I believe is preventing the model from understanding the task that I'm giving it.
Here is an example of one of the term broken up:
Tokenized text: ['NE', 'O', 'PL', 'ASM', 'ĠOF', 'ĠUNS', 'PEC', 'IFIED', 'ĠBE', 'HAV', 'IOR', 'ĠOF', 'ĠEN', 'DO', 'CR', 'INE', 'ĠGL', 'AND', 'S', 'ĠAND', 'ĠOTHER', 'ĠPART', 'S', 'ĠOF', 'ĠN', 'ER', 'VO', 'US', 'ĠSYSTEM']

I used unsloth to train llama 3 and it worked well for me.  That doesn't mean other options won't work even better.  For multiple words you can treat them as a phrase.

What size model did you use? I tried with Llama 3.1 8B and it didn't work
